# It is not displaying number in string

Tags: jquery

I am using this code below to state which table row (question number) the error is occurred in.

```
 var _qid = $("td.qid", this).text();
 var _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";
```

The code above goes into the validation function below:

```
 function validation() {

     var _qid = $("td.qid", this).text();
     var _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";

    alertValidation= "";
        // Note, this is just so it's declared...


    $(".textAreaQuestion").each(function() {
        if (!this.value || this.value.length < 5) {
            alertValidation += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question\n";
        }

            if(alertValidation != ""){ 
                return false;//Stop the each loop 
            } 
    });

        $(".numberAnswerTxtRow").each(function() {
       var currenttotal = $(this).closest('.optionAndAnswer').find('.answerBtnsOn') .length; 

        if (!this.value) {
            alertValidation += "\nPlease Enter in the Number of Answers you Require for this question\n";
        }

    if(alertValidation != ""){ 
                return false;//Stop the each loop 
            } 

    });
```

The problem is that it is not displaying the number. It is displaying this "You have errors on Question Number: " but it does not show the question number after the semi colon. How can I get the number to appear?

Below is the code which adds each table row and adding the question number column in the added rows (table row 1 is question number 1, table row 2 is question number 2 and etc):

```
var qnum = 1; 

function insertQuestion(form) {   

    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody');  
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>"); 
    var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>"); 

$tr.append($qid); 
$tbody.append($tr);  

   $(form).find('.numberOfQuestions').val(qnum); 

    ++qnum; 
    $("#questionNum").text(qnum); 

}
```

Below is the html the added rows are added into:

```
<table id="qandatbl" align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="qid">Question No</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

The validation is checked by the myclickHander() function like this:

```
function myClickHandler(){
     if(validation()){
                showConfirm();
     }
}
```

The myClickHandler() function is called from a submit button like this:

```
<p><input id="submitBtn" name="submitDetails" type="submit" value="Submit Details" onClick="myClickHandler(); return false;" /></p>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Have you checked it contains what you think it is?

Comment: Well, what does `_qid` contain? Apparently not what you think it does. What does `this` refer to?

Comment: What does `this` refer to? Could you post the HTML as well, and preferably a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: 'var _qid = $("td.qid", this).text();' What is "this" in this statement?

Comment: I will add html, give me 2 mins. What happens is the code in the jquery adds a row into the html table, so td.qid is refering to the table column in the jquery (`var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>"); `)

Comment: Where do you have the "you have errors.." code? It doesn't work correctly or at all unless `this` refers to the td's parent.

Comment: It's still unclear where the first two lines are in your code, and that's the crucial part.

Comment: I will include whole validation function, give me 2 mins, first two lines of code is in that function

Comment: And how are you calling `validation`?

Comment: I have edited question to include how I am calling validation().

Answer (score 0):

Your context is missing when you assign qid. 
It is only valid inside the context of

```
$("tr"). Click(function (){ 
    // the context is valid here
})
```

otherwise your code don't know which td you're referring to.

If you are triggering the event by a button here something more related.
your HTML page

```
<table border="1" width="200">
    <tr>
        <td class='qid'>1</td> 
        <td><input id="question1" class="question"  value="This is valid"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='qid'>2</td>
        <td><input id="question2" class="question" value="not"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='qid'>3</td>
        <td><input id="question3" class="question" value="This is also valid"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

Then the code

```
function test(){

    $(".question").each(function(i,e){
        if(e.value.length < 5){
            console.log(e.id);
            var _qid = $("#"+e.id).parent().parent().eq(0).text();
            //console.log(_qid)
            alert("You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid);
        }
    }) 
}
```

I also put it in jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/franky/bAbb9/

I hope this is helping.

Comment: Can I simply do a $("tr") function because I don't want to click on a row and then the alert would appear? How is the code suppose to be written to be able to find the table row?

Comment: Ok, so you have a table with some ID in the header.  The user click a submit button then you parse the table and want to return a message with the ID relative to the cell (TD) where you found the error?

Comment: I change my answer to be trigger by a **button click** instead of row click.